# Disabling layer uploading in GeoNode

Tags: layers, ubuntu, geonode, disable

I'm using GeoNode on my Ubuntu 16.04. I want to disable layer publishing for all users and enable that just for a group of users. How can I do that?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Specify the version of GeoNode you are using. I suggest reading the GeoNode documentation about groups, roles and people management from the administration panel . Also have a look at your "Settings.py" or "local_settings.py" files.

Answer (score 0):

You can change permissions of groups and users through the Admin menu option. More advice can be found in the [help file](https://doc-geonode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/004_admin_workshop/001_admin_panel/users-groups.html).